# Spring-Security Login With Hibernate returns Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to get my hands on Spring boot with hibernate and Spring-Security. I am stuck while trying to login using spring-security and was finding it difficult to debug with some weird issue.

My code enters "loadUserByUsername(String login)" from where I call "userDAO.getUser(login)". In  getUser(login) I have printed **logs which are not getting printed after the createQuery code line** and I get "Bad credentials" message on UI from login.

Below are the logs that get printed : -

> 2014-04-03 22:38:54.150  INFO 4587 [tomcat-http--6] ---
>   service.CustomUserDetailsService         : XXX loadUserByUsername
>
> 2014-04-03 22:38:54.151  INFO 4587 [tomcat-http--6] ---
>   model.implementation.UserDAOImpl         : XXX Login name : -admin
>
> 2014-04-03 22:38:54.152  INFO 4587 [tomcat-http--6] ---
>   model.implementation.UserDAOImpl         : XXX User Query0  2014-04-03

I cant understand why the other logs below this are not printed and how my code moves out of the method without any errors in logs.

You can also check the complete code at https://github.com/himanshuvirmani/Spring-Boot-Security-Example

Some code snippets below

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.info("XXX loadUserByUsername");
        AdminUser domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        logger.info("XXX User name " + domainUser.getLogin());
        logger.info("XXX User Role " + domainUser.getRole().getRole());
        return new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(), 
                domainUser.getPassword(), 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
        );
    }


public AdminUser getUser(String login) {
        logger.info("XXX Login name : -" + login);
        List<AdminUser> userList = new ArrayList<AdminUser>();
        logger.info("XXX User Query0 ");
        Query query = openSession().createQuery("from AdminUser u where u.login = :login");
        logger.info("XXX User Query1 ");
        query.setParameter("login", login);
        logger.info("XXX User Query2 : -");
        userList = query.list();        
        if (userList.size() > 0)
            return userList.get(0);
        else
            return null;    
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any exception? The HQL query should be 
`from AdminUser u where u.login = :login`. It could be explanation why other log messages are not printed.

Comment: Yeah, My bad.. But changing to AdminUser too has no impact. Still it seams the code ends on that query only. I have configured Hibernate logs using logback.xml like below. Do I need to do anything extra to see any exception etc from hibernate.

Comment: <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="ALL" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL" />

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I figured out the problem and mentioning below so that it might help if someone faces this issue.

Here hibernate's createQuery method throws exception but the same exception does not appear in console or spring logs. So it is preferable to that you catch all hibernate query statements with try/catch so that you are always aware if something bad happens. it should be something like below : -

```
public AdminUser getUser(String login) {
    List<AdminUser> userList = new ArrayList<AdminUser>();
    try {
    Query query = openSession().createQuery("FROM model.AdminUser u WHERE u.login = :login");       
    query.setParameter("login", login);
    logger.debug("XXX query : -" + query.getQueryString());
    userList = query.list();
    } catch(HibernateException e){
        logger.error("XXX Hibernate exception occured");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```